# How do I ensure that the right app.config is being loaded?

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a console app, let's call it `Test.Console`. This app uses a project called `Test.Code`.

`Test.Code` is a wrapper to access a database and should have an `app.config` file containing the connection string.

`Test.Console` should then access the classes in `Test.Code` to access what's in the database.

However, when I put the connection string in the app.config in the Code project, it doesn't seem to be able to access it, but when I put it in app.config in the Console project, the code in the Code project seems to be able to access it.

Is there any way that I can put the connection string in the Code project rather than the Console project?

**Edit:**

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="ACE" connectionString="data source=servername;database=ACE;userid=username;password=password"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

In my class:

```
string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACE"].ConnectionString;
```

That's it at the moment.

Comment: Could you post your app.config and your code where you read connections string? As I understand situation, there should not be any problem reading this settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app.config is exactly that, configuration for the running application.

The running application should be in charge of what databases etc that it connects to, hence the reason the config goes there.

Comment: But I don't want that. I want the wrapper class to control the database. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: There is no built in way of doing this as it just was not designed this way.